# El campo año está oculto en el DatePickerDialog de Android Oreo

Tags: android, datepicker, diálogo

Tengo un código que está funcionando correctamente en todas las versiones anteriores a la 8.0 (api 26).
Al ejecutar mi app en un teléfono con Android 8.1 oculta el año (no permite seleccionar un año anterior o posterior), mostrando en la parte superior solamente el día y el mes. En las versiones anteriores se muestra sobre el título "día, mes", el año (editable). 
En la versión Oreo de Android a pesar de que está oculto, si tocás en el borde superior del componente (un poco más arriba del título "día, mes") se hace visible el campo año y cambia la interfaz para seleccionar el año deseado. ¿Será un bug de la api 27?
Si alguien tiene la solución para que esté siempre visible el año, se lo agradezco.
P.D.: En el emulador de Android Studio sobre un virtual con la versión 8.1 me lo muestra bien, como siempre, el calendario completo para seleccionar día, mes y año, es decir, sin el "error".
Agrego las capturas de los dos ejemplos (izquierda: Android 7.0 - derecha: Android 8.1)
[image: A la izquierda version Android 7.0 y a la derecha Android 8.1]

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Gerardo, te recomiendo agregar más detalles, una imagen o el código que estas usando, revisar [ask] , te recomiendo editar tu pregunta para que obtengas buenas respuestas, no olvides revisar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sito, saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias @Jorgesys